# k-d tree in solidity for efficient search operation

Tags: solidity, dapp-development, dapp-design

Let us consider the following example

```
contract Courses {

    struct Instructor {
        uint age;
        string fName;
        string lName;
    }

    mapping (address => Instructor) instructors;
    address[] public instructorAccts;

}
```

If I want to search `instructor` by `fName` or `lName` I will have to iterate all the records stored in `mapping instructors`.

The time complexity of search operation sequentially is **O(N)**. The time complexity of search operation can be reduced using a data structure [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree). Is there any example available for the same in solidity?